# Aggregate lists in a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2], 'B':['x','x','y','y','x','x','y','y'], 'C':[[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[8,9,10,11],[12,13,14],[15],[16,17,18],[],[19]]})
```

I'm trying to aggregate `C` so I tried

```
df.groupby('A')['C'].agg(['mean','std'])
```

But I get an error

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *may* be able to do this by doing some trickery inside a `lambda` function. But, for the sake of sanity and performance, I'd suggest just flattening your data before doing anything like this.

---

First, flatten your columns:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['C'])

df_new = pd.DataFrame(
    df[cols].values.repeat(df.C.str.len(), axis=0), columns=cols
)
df_new['C'] = np.concatenate(df['C'])

df_new.head(10)

   A  B     C
0  1  x   1.0
1  1  x   2.0
2  1  x   3.0
3  1  x   4.0
4  1  x   5.0
5  1  x   6.0
6  1  y   8.0
7  1  y   9.0
8  1  y  10.0
9  1  y  11.0
```

Now, call `groupby`:

```
df_new.groupby('A')['C'].agg(['mean','std'])

        mean       std
A                     
1   7.538462  4.351540
2  17.000000  1.581139
```

Compare this with the messy alternative:

```
fncs = [
     ('mean', lambda x: np.concatenate(x.values).mean()), 
     ('std',  lambda x: np.std(np.concatenate(x.values)))
]
df.groupby('A').C.agg(fncs)

        mean       std
A                     
1   7.538462  4.180824
2  17.000000  1.414214
```